# Skepticism of afterlife in Vedanta

Tags: vedanta, rebirth

Are there any Hindu scriptures or saints which accept existence of Atman but raise doubt on whether afterlife exists or not?

Comment: I highly doubt that this can be the view of any acharya within Hinduism. To be a Hindu is to accept Vedas. To accept Vedas is to affirm the Karma theory, to affirm Karma is to believe that afterlife (at least in some form) exists.

Comment: Your question is essentially - Are there any Hindus who are non-Hindus. It makes no sense.

Comment: I do not belive in after life and yet I belive in Karma. We get fruits of Karma instantly. I'm trying to find out if there are more Hindus like me.